# Perpetual motion machines

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Out of pure curiosity, after seeing a few really awesome perpetual motion machine ideas on youtube, I decided to try it out in blender as an exercise.
In addition, I thought, that would be cool to have a rigid body system driven by one of the perpetual motion ideas, instead of existing "motor" constraint or animated object.

Of course, I understand that perpetual motion is impossible in real world, but, I believe, it can be achieved in computer simulation, by (cheating) tweaking some properties, friction or gravity for example.

So, I am trying to recreate the examples from here https://youtu.be/jsxroTt9IhY?t=91,
 and from here https://youtu.be/1hYYdmjuDac?t=146

However, both simulation does'n work as expected and it seems, the system balances itself even, no matter how hard I'd try.

Here are my test blends:

Ball & Levelers
[image]

Rolling Ball Wheel
[image]

Is that possible to achieve that in blender simulation at all ?

Edit: just found this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KeQc-vH46U

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: please add some detail about what you tried and a specific thing not working... also use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your .blend files (free, permanent, integrated) then past the provided link editing your post.

Comment: Maybe, probably, but for physical accuracy I would give it up with Blender. Check this, it's my favorite: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyjE5L4-1lQ :) The last example you've posted was made in BGE, it's physics system was quite different as far as I know. So in my opinion - don't bother with it. It will be hard and frustrating as hell.

Comment: Wow, the video is actually from 2012, and looks very nice!

Comment: Can you add some pictures/gifs of what you have?